# Google Transliterator (input tools) is not suggesting words as typed when used on my site

Tags: google, internationalization, google-workspace, translation, international

I want a transliterator (Google's) to be embedded in my site. I tried embedding it and I mostly succeeded. It is showing translations, but all of them for a word typed one letter at a time like it shows in Google input tools online like this:

[image]

I need such a feature in my site, however it is only showing me at the end of the word when I hit space, not after every key press.

I tried looking at the web console (Firefox), and understood that in the code that I have is sending a request whenever we hit a space. But [Google input tools](http://www.google.co.in/inputtools/try/) online is sending request to POST a request after every key press then getting and printing data only after space.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Is it that it is updating on space press on your website, and on keypress on a google website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you code in an event listener that pings for every keypress instead of the default space / enter key press?

Google Search API and widgets usually have an auto-suggest option, which works the same as you want this to. However, I couldn't find an exact equivalent for the transliterate API, so your only option would be code this in yourself.